# How to print model items in a template file?

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to show in the template file how many users I have and how many from them chose a language exam in English

How to display this information in an admin template file? (base.html) I tried something like this:

```
{{users.count()}}
```

I added an application "Userprofile" which is the form that user can choose an exam's language

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    JEZYK = (
        ('DE', 'niemiecki'),
        ('FR', 'francuski'),
        ('EN', 'angielski'),
    )
    jezyk_egzaminu = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=JEZYK, verbose_name='jezyk')
```

How can I show in a template file how many users chose 'EN', 'angielski' option ?

Thanks Catavaran I tried this solution but I do something wrong :(

I saved a file in a main project app "aplikacja" (aplikacja/aplikacja)

[image: As you can see at the photo]

I added in base.html

{% load mytags %}

```
<div>Total users: {% user_count %}</div>
<div>English users: {% user_count 'EN' %}</div>
```

I get an error as return /admin/ site

Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:

> 'mytags' is not a valid tag library: Template library mytags not
>   found, tried
>   django.templatetags.mytags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.mytags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.mytags

Comment: Provide the code of the view also. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the following context to the template:

```
{'users': UserProfile.objects.all(),
 'en_users': UserProfile.objects.filter(jezyk_egzaminu='EN')}
```

And then call `count()` method:

```
<div>Total users: {{ users.count }}</div>
<div>English users: {{ en_users.count }}</div>
```

If you want to get user count in the admin's `base.html` then you have to create [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template
from myapp.models import UserProfile

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def user_count(lang=None):
    users = UserProfile.objects.all()
    if lang:
        users = users.filter(jezyk_egzaminu=lang)
    return users.count()
```

This code should be in the `profil/templatetags/mytags.py` file.  And don't forget to create empty `profil/templatetags/__init__.py` file. [See the docs for code layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout).

Usage of this template tag in the `base.html`:

```
{% load mytags %}

<div>Total users: {% user_count %}</div>
<div>English users: {% user_count 'EN' %}</div>
```

Comment: How to pass the those contexts to the template? I try to show this in admin's template base.html

Comment: catavaran could you take a look please at my updated question? I tried your solutions but I do something in wrong way :( Thank you very much!

Comment: The code layout for template tags described in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout I updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typing error in the code.  Function definition should be: `def user_count(lang=None)`